# How to use or enable git Trace2 API for jgit?

Tags: git, jgit

Using git trace 2 to analyze performane issues for git commands is great. We have a new application  now, which uses the jgit api and a local git repository. Since there are performance issues, I would like to use git trace2 (GIT_TRACE_PERFORMANCE) to analyze the different jgit commands that are invoked on the git repository. Git trace2 is enabled in the .git/config and it works with direct git commands, but not for jgit calls.

Anyone experience with using git trace2 and jgit? Is it possible to use it for jgit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that JGit does not implement trace 2, at least I couldn't find the string `GIT_TRACE_PERFORMANCE` in the code base.

I suggest to use a Java profiler like YourKit, or VisualVM, or similar to investigate performance issues.

Comment: I tried the Java profiler in VisualVM, it helped to isolate the issue. Thanks for this approach.